# Integrate an indicator against Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I'm trying to understand why $\int_{0}^{T}\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}(W(t))dW(t) \neq (W(T) - K)^{+}$, $W(\cdot)$ is a Brownian motion. I know $E[\int_{0}^{T}\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}(W(t))dW(t)]= 0$ since Ito integrals are martingale and $E[(W(T) - K)^{+}]>0$. But fix a path $\omega$, it falls into three cases.

Case 1: The path never goes above $K$. Then LHS = RHS = $0$. 
Case 2: The path has reached K in $[0,T]$ and $W(T) < K$. For every time $t_{enter}$ that $W(t)$ reaches $(K,\infty)$, there must be a $t_{leave}$ such that $W(t)$ leaves $(K,\infty)$. $\int_{t_{enter}}^{t_{leave}}\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}(W(t))dW(t) = \int_{t_{enter}}^{t_{leave}}1dW(t) = W(t_{leave}) - W(t_{enter}) = K - K = 0$. Summing up across all entering and leaving times, $\int_{0}^{T}\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}(W(t))dW(t) = 0 = (W(T) - K)^{+}$.
Case 3: The path has reached K in $[0,T]$ and $W(T) \geq K$. Suppose $t_{enter} = sup\{s < T: W(s) < K\}$, i.e. the last entering time. Then all previous entering and leaving integrates to zero, then $\int_{0}^{T}\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}(W(t))dW(t) = \int_{t_{enter}}^{T}1dW(t) = W(T) - W(t_{enter})$ = $(W(T) - K)^{+}$.

What went wrong with the argument? I'm guessing there might be uncountable enterings and leavings to $(K,\infty)$ so we can't take the sum.

Comment: Are you possibly thinking about and getting confused with the result
$\int^T_0W(t)\,\text{d}W(t)=\frac{1}{2}\big(W(T)^2-T\big)$?

Comment: The result you posed makes sense to me. I'm confused why we can't integrate $\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}(W(t))dW(t)$ by "direct computation": between consecutive entering and leaving time of $(k,\infty)$, the integrand is 1, so the integral is the difference between the Brownian motion at leaving and entering times, i.e. $K-K = 0$

Comment: @g.s Thank you! $\int_{0}^{T} \mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}dW(t) = \int_{0}^{T} \mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}d(W(t) - K)$ = $\int_{0}^{T} d\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}(W(t) - K) - \int_{0}^T (W(t) - K) d\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)} -  \int_{0}^T d(W(t) - K) d\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}$ = $(W(t) - K)^{+} - \int_{0}^T (W(t) - K) d\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)} -  \int_{0}^T d(W(t) - K) d\mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}$, while the latter two terms are not zero. Is this what you hint for?

Comment: @ g.s One more thought. I think it might have to do with the fact that the integral is $\lim_{|\Pi| \downarrow 0} \mathbb{1}_{(k,\infty)}(W(t_j))(W(t_{j+1})-W(t_j))$, with the value of indicator taken at the left hand side of $[t_j, t_{j+1}]$. But fixing a partition $\{t_0 = 0, t_1,...,t_{n-1}, t_n = T\}$, almost surely the last entering time of $(k,\infty)$ is to the right of $t_{n-1}$, so it's not right to think that the last time the Brownian motion entering $(k,\infty)$ without leaving leads to a positive integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct treatment of $\int_0^T1_{(K,\infty)}(W(t))\,dW(t)$ is achieved by means of the [Tanaka formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka%27s_formula) by which
$$\tag{1}
|W(T)|=\int_0^T{\rm sign}(W(t))\,dW(t)+L_T(0)
$$
and $L_T(0)$ is the Brownian local time that measures how many times $W(t)$ crosses the point at zero.
From
$$
{\rm sign}(x)=1_{(x,\infty)}-1_{(-\infty,x)}
$$
and
$$
|x|=\max(x,0)-\min(x,0)
$$
it is not that surprising that there is also a one-sided version of
(1):
$$\tag{2}
(W(T)-K)^+=\int_0^T1_{(K,\infty)}(W(t))\,dW(t)+\frac{1}{2}L_T(K)
$$
See for example Borodin & Salminen, *Handbook of Brownian Motion*, p.43.